# Regular Expression with python

Tags: python, regex

I have a tricky regular expression and I can't succeed to implement it.

I need the regular expression for this :

```
AEBE52E7-03EE-455A-B3C4-E57283966239
```

I use it for an identification like this :

```
url(r'^user/(?P<identification>\<regular expression>)$', 'view_add')
```

I tried some expressions like these ones:

```
\[A-Za-z0-9]{8}^-{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}^-{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}^-{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}^-{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}
```

```
\........^-....^-....^-....^-............
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What are all those circumflexes for? They make it impossible for your regex to match *anything*. And what's with the backslash at the beginning? (On an other note; `{1}` is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove all the `^` symbols present in your regex.

```
>>> s = 'AEBE52E7-03EE-455A-B3C4-E57283966239'
>>> re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}$', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 36), match='AEBE52E7-03EE-455A-B3C4-E57283966239'>
>>> re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}$', s).group()
'AEBE52E7-03EE-455A-B3C4-E57283966239'
```

`-{1}` would be written as `-`  It seems like all delimited words are hex codes. So you could use `[0-9a-fA-F]` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9]` .

```
>>> re.match(r'[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$', s).group()
'AEBE52E7-03EE-455A-B3C4-E57283966239'
```

Comment: Same remark: `[0-9a-fA-F]` is more appropriate for GUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `^` and for `-` dont need `{1}`,you can use the following pattern :

```
\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}
```

*Note* that `\w` will match any word character (`A-Za-z0-9`)

Or :

```
\w{8}-(\w{4}-){3}\w{12}
```

And as mentioned in comment if you are using a UUID as a more efficient way you can use the following pattern :

```
[a-fA-F\d]{8}(-[a-fA-F\d]{4}){3}-[a-fA-F\d]{12}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kE6rO0/1)

Comment: Come on, that's a GUID... `[0-9a-fA-F]` is much more appropriate than `\w`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski where is `A-F`?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski aha, yeah i miss that its UUID!